# How to adjust the breaks of legends in stat_summary_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to adjust the breaks of legends in stat_summary_2d?

```
templ = data.frame(count = c(200,225,610,233,250,210,290,255,279,250),
                   temperature = c(12.2,11.6,12,8.5,4,8.2,9.2,10.6,10.8,10.9),
                   relative_humidity_percent = c(74,78,72,65,77,84,83,74,73,75))

heatf_65 = templ%>% 
  ggplot(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, z =count*1.05)) +
  stat_summary_2d() +
  #geom_point(shape = 1, col = 'white') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = c(seq(180,650,100)))+ 
  xlab('Daily Mean Temperature (°C)') +
  ylab('Daily Mean Relative Humidity Percent (%)') +
  ggtitle('Admission rate (per 100000 population)') +
  theme_classic() +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title() 
#scale_fill_binned_sequential(palette = "Terrain", rev = FALSE)
```

The outcome:
[image]

The scale of legend is not the same as my setting. I have already tried

```
heatf_65 = templ%>% 
  ggplot(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, z =count*1.05)) +
  stat_summary_2d(breaks = c(seq(180,650,100))) +
  #geom_point(shape = 1, col = 'white') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()+ 
  xlab('Daily Mean Temperature (°C)') +
  ylab('Daily Mean Relative Humidity Percent (%)') +
  ggtitle('Admission rate (per 100000 population)') +
  theme_classic() +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title() 
#scale_fill_binned_sequential(palette = "Terrain", rev = FALSE)
```

The outcome is:
[image]

Is it possible to adjust the breaks without using other extra function?

Comment: Could you clarify what's the issue or your desired outcome? The breaks for the legend could be set via `scale_fill_xxx` as you did in your first code. The `breaks` argument of stat_summary_2d defines the binning of the x and y variable (Interesting that this argument works as it is not mentioned in the docs).

Comment: My desired outcome is to set the breaks at c(180,280,380,480,580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that only the breaks which fit inside the `limits` will be shown in the legend. Hence, to show the lowest value of your breaks you also have to set the lower limit accordingly:

```r
library(ggplot2)

templ |> 
  ggplot(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, z = count * 1.05)) +
  stat_summary_2d() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = seq(180, 650, 100), limits = c(180, NA)) +
  xlab("Daily Mean Temperature (°C)") +
  ylab("Daily Mean Relative Humidity Percent (%)") +
  ggtitle("Admission rate (per 100000 population)") +
  theme_classic() +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title()
```

[image]